# How can I create columns based on the first 6 cells from a csv file?

Tags: r, csv

[image]

So what I need to do is create columns with the values stated on the first 9 lines... The value at cell A1, for example, should be at E9 and the value at  B1 should be at E10, E11, E12, E13, ...

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: `read_csv()` from the `readr` package allows you to indicate what columns and rows of data you want to read in and save as an object. I would first read in the data frame, and then read in the specific values in the first few rows as separate objects that you would then merge as desired to the data frame.

Comment: In this case, can you please [edit] your question and include the first 13 (or so) rows of the CSV file raw contents (into a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fake CSV data, stored as `"foo.csv"`:

```
REG,CO
UF,DF
ESTACAO,BRASILIA
Date,Hora,PRECIP,TEMP
01/01/2020,0000 UTC,0,20
01/01/2000,0100 UTC,0,19.5
01/01/2000,0200 UTC,0,21
```

Reading it in, finding the "real" header row, then moving on:

```r
alldat <- readLines("foo.csv")
alldat
# [1] "REG,CO"                     "UF,DF"                      "ESTACAO,BRASILIA"           "Date,Hora,PRECIP,TEMP"     
# [5] "01/01/2020,0000 UTC,0,20"   "01/01/2000,0100 UTC,0,19.5" "01/01/2000,0200 UTC,0,21"  
ind <- grep("Hora", alldat)
ind
# [1] 4
```

From here, we can determine both the header info and the rest of the data:

```r
header <- as.data.frame(t(read.csv(text = alldat[1:(ind-1)], header = FALSE, row.names = 1L)))
header
#    REG UF  ESTACAO
# V2  CO DF BRASILIA
rest_of_data <- read.csv(text = alldat[ind:(length(alldat))])
rest_of_data
#         Date     Hora PRECIP TEMP
# 1 01/01/2020 0000 UTC      0 20.0
# 2 01/01/2000 0100 UTC      0 19.5
# 3 01/01/2000 0200 UTC      0 21.0
```

We can then `cbind` them:

```r
rownames(header) <- NULL
cbind(rest_of_data, header)
#         Date     Hora PRECIP TEMP REG UF  ESTACAO
# 1 01/01/2020 0000 UTC      0 20.0  CO DF BRASILIA
# 2 01/01/2000 0100 UTC      0 19.5  CO DF BRASILIA
# 3 01/01/2000 0200 UTC      0 21.0  CO DF BRASILIA
```

(Clearing the row names was purely to preempt a warning when `cbind`ing, it is not strictly required.)